# Rails 4 - Removed sqlite3 gem - "Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I've looked on as many existing answers as I can, but I can't figure out why heroku is still trying to install sqlite3.  Below is my gemfile, I don't even have sqlite3 on it anymore, as I am using mysql in development, test, and production.  What am I missing?  I don't see any dependencies either?

I get the error `Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku` when trying to push.

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'thin'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

#mysql
gem 'mysql2'


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

#tagging
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'

#debugger
gem 'debugger'

#backup db with yaml_db
gem 'yaml_db', github: 'jetthoughts/yaml_db', ref: 'fb4b6bd7e12de3cffa93e0a298a1e5253d7e92ba'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: Check if your Gemfile.lock has Sqlite3? If so, remove Gemfile.lock, do bundle install, get new lock file, and check-in the code. Push it and see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you've probably not rebuilt your `Gemfile.lock`. The way to do this is to run `bundle install` on your development system (rebuilds `Gemfile.lock`) and then push to Heroku again:

```
$ bundle install
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "SQLite3"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: I'm still having the problem.  I tried removing the .lock file and rebundling, but sqlite3 remains in the new generated .lock file.